# What is the color code for transparency in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-color

Can anyone tell me what is the color code for transparency in CSS like white = "#FFFFFF"? As I am using following code, to convert the color codes into int:

```
Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
return (int)((color.R << 16) | (color.G << 8) | (color.B << 0));
```

Comment: There is none.  The RGB model does not include transparency. There needs to be a fourth channel for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a color code for transparent in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189201/is-there-a-color-code-for-transparent-in-html)

Comment: Yes, there is for certain browsers (new feature). Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876347/2457251

Answer (score 12, accepted):

how to make transparent elements with css:

**CSS for IE:**

```
filter: alpha(opacity = 52);
```

**CSS for other browsers:**

```
opacity:0.52;
```

Comment: There is also the `transparent` key word. p { background-color:transparent; }

Answer (score 17):

There is no hex code for transparency. For CSS, you can use either `transparent` or `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 13):

Or you could just put

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
```

That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Simply choose your background color of your item and specify the opacity separatly:

```
div { background-color:#000; opacity:0.8; }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no transparency component of the color hex string. There is `opacity`, which is a float from 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
background-color: none;
```

that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are now 8-digit hex codes in CSS4 ([CSS Color Module Level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#hex-notation)), the last two digit (or in case of the abbreviation, the last of the 4 digits) represents alpha, `00` meaning fully transparent and `ff` meaning fully opaque, `7f` representing an opacity of 0.5 etc.

The format is `'#rrggbbaa'` or the shorthand, `'#rgba'`.

Support is lacking for MS browsers, they might be less cooperative or just slower than the other developers, either or both of which actually sealed IE's fate: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa

Answer (score 0):

jus add two zeroes (00) before your color code you will get the transparent of that color

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS write:

```
.exampleclass {
    background:#000000;
    opacity: 10; /* you can always adjust this */
}
```

Comment: opacity: 1; is already 100% - 0.5 means 50% and so on.

Answer (score -1):

check column name should be renaemed as something name as our wish but coumn should not be check

Ex: check column name should be renamed as language

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Either that or I've horribly failed to understand.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30974682)

Answer (score -2):

Simply put:

```
.democlass {
    background-color: rgba(246,245,245,0);
}
```

That should give you a transparent background.