# Transparent ARGB hex value

Tags: colors, hex, argb

The colors in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx) table is all not transparent. I guess the value for the `A` is set to `FF`.

What is the code for transparency?

For example this color FFF0F8FF (AliceBlue), to a transparent code such as `??F0F8FF` ?

Comment: Finally there is a way to set transparent color with hex code for certain browsers (new feature). Please, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876347/2457251

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Transparency is controlled by the alpha channel (`AA` in `#AARRGGBB`). Maximal value (255 dec, FF hex) means fully opaque. Minimum value (0 dec, 00 hex) means fully transparent. Values in between are semi-transparent, i.e. the color is mixed with the background color.

To get a fully transparent color set the alpha to zero. `RR`, `GG` and `BB` are irrelevant in this case because no color will be visible. This means `#00FFFFFF` ("transparent White") is the same color as `#00F0F8FF` ("transparent AliceBlue").
To keep it simple one chooses black (`#00000000`) or white (`#00FFFFFF`) if the color does not matter.

In the table you linked to you'll find `Transparent` defined as `#00FFFFFF`.

Comment: let's say I need 50% opacity. What is the code for white color with 50% opacity/transparent?

Comment: @user3332579: 50% is `7F`. Put your calculator in hex mode, it will do the trick for you.

Comment: @user3332579: So 50% white is `#7FFFFFFF`.

Comment: The format is #RRGGBBAA Hex8 (or #RGBA in Hex4) and **NOT** #AARRGGBB (or #ARGB)
I have tested in Chrome 62,63,64
Refer to [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=%23rrggbbaa) , 

[https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/](https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/) , 

[Chrome Feature Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5685348285808640)

Comment: @SGSSandhu The question is not targeted at CSS. See the question again, the format is ARGB.

Comment: It's important if you're using gradients - otherwise blending through white will show traces of grey.

Answer (score 593):

Here is the table of % to hex values:

**Example**: For 85% white, you would use `#D9FFFFFF`.
**Here 85% = "D9" & White = "FFFFFF"**

```html
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

**How is it calculated?**

Quoting [maleta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828301/maleta) in a now-deleted comment:

> FF is number written in hex mode. That number represent 255 in
> decimal. For example, if you want 42% to calculate you need to find
> 42% of numbeer 255 and convert that number to hex. 255 * 0.42 ~= 107
> 107 to hex is "6B
> -- maleta (*2016-12-27 10:32:28Z, License: CC BY-SA 3.0*)

Comment: how do you calculate this?

Comment: @SaeedJassani FF is number written in hex mode. That number represent 255 in decimal. For example, if you want 42% to calculate you need to find 42% of numbeer 255 and convert that number to hex.  255 * 0.42 ~= 107 107 to hex is "6B"

Comment: Most all modern browsers now support `#rrggbbaa` notation now _(where the aa is the transparency alpha channel)_. See which ones do... https://caniuse.com/css-rrggbbaa.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the other answers and doing nothing more of what @Maleta explained in a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/28481374/1626594, doing **alpha*255 then round then to hex**. Here's a quick converter http://jsfiddle.net/8ajxdLap/4/

```js
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  var rgbm = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?((?:[0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)[\s+]?\)/i);
  if (rgbm && rgbm.length === 5) {
    return "#" +
      ('0' + Math.round(parseFloat(rgbm[4], 10) * 255).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2) +
      ("0" + parseInt(rgbm[1], 10).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2) +
      ("0" + parseInt(rgbm[2], 10).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2) +
      ("0" + parseInt(rgbm[3], 10).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2);
  } else {
    var rgbm = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
    if (rgbm && rgbm.length === 4) {
      return "#" +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgbm[1], 10).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgbm[2], 10).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgbm[3], 10).toString(16).toUpperCase()).slice(-2);
    } else {
      return "cant parse that";
    }
  }
}

$('button').click(function() {
  var hex = rgb2hex($('#in_tb').val());
  $('#in_tb_result').html(hex);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Convert RGB/RGBA to hex #RRGGBB/#AARRGGBB:<br>
<br>
<input id="in_tb" type="text" value="rgba(200, 90, 34, 0.75)"> <button>Convert</button><br>
<br> Result: <span id="in_tb_result"></span>
```

Answer (score 8):

**BE AWARE**

In **HTML/CSS** (browser code) the format is `#RRGGBBAA` with the alpha channel as last two hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 4):

Just use this:

```
android:background="#00FFFFFF"
```

it will do your work.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this and the short code for transparency is simply #00000000.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your hex value, and your just wondering what the value for the alpha would be, this snippet may help:

```js
const alphaToHex = (alpha => {
  if (alpha > 1 || alpha < 0 || isNaN(alpha)) {
    throw new Error('The argument must be a number between 0 and 1');
  }
  return Math.ceil(255 * alpha).toString(16).toUpperCase();
})

console.log(alphaToHex(0.45));
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard hex color code has six characters eg #000000 - black, and the hex color code with more than six characters(likely 8 characters eg #82bc00 - green) exceeds the standard amount making the other two last characters define the transparency level.
so if you need to attain absolute transparency you can add 00 to any hex color but for uniformity you can just use #00000000

```css
.green{
  background: #82bc00      /*actual green*/
}
.subgreen{
  background: #82bc0070    /*green with little transparency*/
}
.greenparency{
  background: #82bc0040    /*green with much transparency*/
}
.transparency{
  background: #82bc0000    /*full transparency over green*/
}
```

```html
<div class="green"> green background color </div>
<div class="subgreen"> green background color </div>
<div class="greenparency"> green background color </div>
<div class="transparency"> green background color </div>
```