# Change Sheet tab color of excel file using Open XML

Tags: openxml

I want to change the sheet tab color of an excel Xlsx  document. I am using the following code but it does not set the sheet color. I get object reference exception when I set the sheet tab color.

```
public static string filepath = @"C:\Test\Book1.xlsx";
private static void ChangeSheetcolor()
{
    try
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            //my code
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart =
                  GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheetDocument, "Sheet1");

            if (worksheetPart != null)
            {
             //   worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties.TabColor.Rgb = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue.FromString("Red");
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties.TabColor.Rgb = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue.FromString("#CCCCCC");
                // Save the worksheet.
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 

    }            
}
private static WorksheetPart
     GetWorksheetPartByName(SpreadsheetDocument document,
     string sheetName)
{
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets =
       document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().
       Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);
    if (sheets.Count() == 0)
    {
        //does not exist
        return null;
    }
    string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)
         document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    return worksheetPart;
}
```

How to change the sheet tab color using Open XML dlls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have 3 issues as far as I can tell. Firstly, the second parameter to the `Open` method you are calling denotes whether or not the file is editable. You need to pass `true` here if you wish to edit the file otherwise you'll hit the following exception upon saving the worksheet:

> System.IO.IOException: Cannot get stream with FileMode.Create, FileMode.CreateNew, FileMode.Truncate, FileMode.Append when access is FileAccess.Read.

Secondly, `SheetProperties` or `TabColor` could be null. In the XSD they are defined as

```
<xsd:element name="sheetPr" type="CT_SheetPr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

and

```
<xsd:element name="tabColor" type="CT_Color" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

Note both have `minOccurs="0"` so either could be null. If they are, you can just create new instances and assign them to the `Worksheet`.

Finally, the `Rgb` property is arguably badly named as the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.tabcolor%28v=office.14%29.aspx) states (emphasis mine):

> Standard **Alpha** Red Green Blue color value (**A**RGB).
>   The possible values for this attribute are defined by the ST_UnsignedIntHex simple type
>   (§18.18.86).

18.18.86 goes on to say (again, emphasis mine):

> This simple type's contents have a length of **exactly 8** hexadecimal digit(s).

Assuming you want a solid color you can set the alpha channel to FF. You also shouldn't include the leading `#` so for a solid red for example you should use `"FFFF0000"`. More details on ARGB values can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201134/transparent-argb-hex-value).

Putting that all together your code becomes something like this:

```
public static string filepath = @"C:\Test\Book1.xlsx";
private static void ChangeSheetcolor()
{
    try
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            //my code
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart =
                    GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheetDocument, "Sheet1");

            if (worksheetPart != null)
            {
                //create the SheetProperties if it doesn't exist
                if (worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties == null)
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties = new SheetProperties();
                //create the TabColor if it doesn't exist
                if (worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties.TabColor == null)
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties.TabColor = new TabColor();
                //this will set the tab color to Red
                //note the value is an ARGB not an RGB
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.SheetProperties.TabColor.Rgb = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.HexBinaryValue.FromString("FFFF0000");
                // Save the worksheet.
                worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```