# Convert ARGB hex string to RGB

Tags: c#, colors, hex, converters

My question is very simular to [Convert RGBA color to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049230/convert-rgba-color-to-rgb) only I have a Hex string not byte colour values.

I am working with [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) and I wish to convery cell background colours to HTML colours.
The cell backgound colours come from this property [ColorType.Rgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.colortype.rgb?view=openxml-2.8.1).
**Note:** The property says Rgb but as the doc says it is actually Argb.

During testing I have one Red cell which has the Argb hex of `#FFFF0000` but as I understand it, in HTML the Alpha is not supported and the Rgb hex for red is `#FF0000`.

I need to first convert the Hex strings to byte values, perform the calculation from the previous answer, convert the Rgb bytes into a hex string.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the Hex string to an integer value using the base 16 as

```
int argb = Convert.ToInt32("0xFFFF0000", 16);
```

and then create your color with

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

finally you can get a new hex string with only RGB values with

```
string rgb = $"#{c.R:X2}{c.G:X2}{c.B:X2}";
```

Comment: Might I ask, what is the `0x`prefix for? I replaced with `#` for HTML colour.

Comment: 0x is the prefix for HEX numbers. But you are correct, you need the # prefix here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
string argb = "#FFFF0000";
string rgb = argb.Remove(1, 2);
```

..since the format of an ARGB hex string is `#AARRGGBB` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201304/8967612)). This is the most straightforward solution (and much faster than solutions based on conversions).

To cover the case of 4 digits instead of 8, you may use something like:

```
int alphaDigits = (argb.Length == 9 ? 2 : 1);
string rgb = argb.Remove(1, alphaDigits);
```

Comment: The ColorTranslator wouldn't work because Argb is not an HTML color, only Rgb is, the ColorTranslator also works for HTML color names like "Red" not the hex "FF0000". The remarks for the `To` method say `This is the commonly used name of a color, such as "Red", "Blue", or "Green", and not string representation of a numeric color value, such as "FF33AA".`

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien 1) I used this as an alternative solution to using `.Remove()` _which is the most straightforward solution_ (and it works as shown above). 2) `ColorTranslator` _**will work**_ because `FromHtml()` uses `ColorConverter.ConvertFrom` [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator.cs,274) which supports ARGB hex values, then `.ToHtml()` just ignores the alpha value. You may test using [this code](https://pastebin.com/h0buePBL) to confirm.

Comment: 3) I already mentioned in the answer that `.ToHtml()` will produce color names when possible (which works for HTML) and resorts to RGB hex values when it's not a known color name. So, it's up to you to decide. If you want to use color names with HTML when possible, you may use the `ColorTranslator` solution. Otherwise, if you prefer to have hex values for all colors, you can either use the `.Remove()` solution or the one provided by Steve in his answer.

Comment: I added the `ColorTranslator` solution as a separate answer to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** This solution, although produces a valid HTML color value, that value doesn't necessarily have to be an RGB hex string as explained below. It's also significantly slower than my other solution.

A third solution would be to use the [`ColorTranslator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator) class, which works because:

- The `ColorTranslator.FromHtml()` method uses `ColorConverter.ConvertFrom` [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/ColorTranslator.cs,274) (which can parse ARGB hex values).
- The `ColorTranslator.ToHtml` then just ignores the alpha value and only uses the RGB values to generate the string<sup>1</sup>.

### Example:

```
Color c = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF0000");
string rgb = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
```

**And here's some test code to show that this solution will work with all possible ARGB hex values:**

```
try
{
    // Incrementing by 5 to save time. We can use `++` to cover all possible values
    // but it will take a long time to execute.
    for (int a = 0; a <= 255; a += 5)
        for (int r = 0; r <= 255; r += 5)
            for (int g = 0; g <= 255; g += 5)
                for (int b = 0; b <= 255; b += 5)
                    ColorTranslator.FromHtml($"#{a.ToString("X2")}{r.ToString("X2")}" +
                                             $"{g.ToString("X2")}{b.ToString("X2")}");
    Console.WriteLine("All is good!");
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed. Message='{ex.Message}'");
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>However, keep in mind that `ColorTranslator.ToHtml()` will not necessarily return an RGB hex string. It tries to return a color name if the color has a known color name (which works for HTML), otherwise, it resorts to RGB hex values in the format of `#RRGGBB`.</sub>