# ggplot2 modify legend for alpha to be in a range of values

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, alpha

I'm trying to generate heat map with `geom_tile`, where the fill of the plot is determined by one parameter and transparency of plot determined by second parameter. I managed to obtain the plot I wanted but failed to make adjustment on the legend for `alpha`.

The continuous data for `alpha` ranged from 38 to 64, but the legend was showing from 40 to 60, which might be misleading.

I would like to adjust the legend so as it started from 0 up to 100. Also, curious why didn't the legend for `alpha` work like `color`, which come with gradient by default.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
> ggplot(mapxspGC_sort, aes(x=Genes, y=SpName, fill=Presence, alpha=GC))+
+ geom_tile() + labs(x="Genes", y="Species",color="%GC")+
+ scale_fill_gradient(low="white",high="black",guide=FALSE)
+ theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(linetype="blank"))
```

Here's part of the long heatmap plot:

[image]

I have tried to add `scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0,100))` and `scale_alpha_continuous(limit=c(0,100))`, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for are the `limits` and `breaks` parameters of `scale_alpha_continuous`:

```
scale_alpha_continuous(limits = c(0,100), breaks = c(0,25,50,100))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Btw, do you have any idea how can I make the legend continuous? Is it actually possible for `alpha`?

Comment: Unfortunately, to my knowledge it isn't possible to make a legend for alpha continuous with ggplot. A hacky work around is to use ```color``` instead of ```alpha``` and use transparent colors (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201134/transparent-argb-hex-value)